# How can I refocus to an input with the cursor after he leaves via focusout via jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to refocus the user in a field immediately after he leaves via `focusout`.  Here when I re-`focus`, it highlights the outside of the input, but doesn't put the cursor back in the field where he can type.  I'll setup a fiddle when their site is not having issues later.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input").focusout(function(){
        alert('unfocus');
    $(this).focus(); //highlights area but I want the cursor returned
    });
});
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/dcoleyoung/details/xzbLf

```
$("input").focusout(function(){
    if(!$(this).valid()){
              //keep user in input
    }

});
```

Comment: Can you please explain what do you mean by you want the cursor returned?

Comment: When the text in the input field is highlighted the input has already got the focus. But what do you mean by `doesn't put the cursor back in the field`? The text is being highlighted only when the field has got focus. What do you mean?

Comment: Rajesh - I want to keep the user editing the input field he just left.

Comment: @Daniel, So basically, if a user's input text is invalid you would like to keep them focused in the input field until it is valid, correct?

Comment: @AnchovyLegend exactly.

Comment: This will drive away users so quickly.

Comment: @BillCriswell my initial approach was to do an entire form validation with .valid() onsubmit but I reached a critical mass of the form (500 inputs) elements that grinded the function to a halt and killed the browser.  I wanted to validate piecemeal/progressively as an alternative.

Comment: You want to handle this situation by validating on submit using `valid()` and not on a per input-basis.. Can you please elaborate on why you need 500 inputs?

Comment: @AnchovyLegend I really appreciate the time you've spent to help me. Basically I have a large matrix in a table that can't be broken up because the form tag can't be split up

Comment: @anchovylegend the table matrix just grew; it used to manageable at 10x10 and I'm trying to see how far I can take it.

Comment: Sure :) I just wanted you to know that there is probably an easier / better way to solve this problem, before answering your initial question... So what is the matrix being used for? You can look into downloading the JQuery `Validate Library` instead of validating everything on your own, it has a bunch of built in functions that make it super easy to validate....

Comment: @AnchovyLegend I took the advice of SO to validate the form in another way.  I wrote my own validate function (simple because only integers) and I'm only validating the modified fields when the form is submitted.  I added a modified class to each changed field and then flag if it fails which is what you had suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend doing so, but if you wish to proceed with this approach despite the SO feedback, you can do something like:

```
//check if .someInput is valid
var valid = false; // input is not valid

while(!valid){
  $('.someInput').focus();
}
```